# e-N proof of a telescoping sum convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Determine whether the following sequences converge or diverge. Prove
your findings. That is, (directly or indirectly, by contradiction) provide
an $\epsilon$ − N proof to establish your findings.

$a_n = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$. Doesn't this converge to zero in every way?

WTS: $\forall \epsilon > 0 $ $\exists N > 0$ s.t. for all $n \in N$, if $n > N$, then $|\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} - 0| < \epsilon$.

$$\bigg|\frac{1}{n^2+n}\bigg| \leq \bigg|\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg| < \frac{1}{N^2}$$ We let N = $\frac{1}{e^{1/2}} > 0$ Therefore

$$\frac{1}{N^2} < \epsilon$$ As required. Is this correct?

Comment: Except that one often asks that $N$ is an integer, and $1/\sqrt{\epsilon}$ is not in general.

Comment: What. Also I forgot to put n > N. Oh I did say that. What do you mean? Isn't this the standard proof?

Comment: Sorry but if you want explanations about my first comment (which frankly does not require any, but...), please post comments that one can understand.

Comment: In $\epsilon$-$N$ proof, we usually have $N\in\Bbb N$. So, in the  problem we can find such $N\in\Bbb N$ (see Archimedean Property) for which $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$ so that if $n>N$ then $$\bigg|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}-0\bigg|=\frac{1}{n^2+n}<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon.$$

Comment: And you have a typo. The $e$ in $N=1/\sqrt e$ should be $\epsilon.$  But you are correct, even though your presentation could use a little polishing.

Comment: Hmm, if you let N = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$ for $\frac{1}{N}$, then that doesn't equal epsilon. Oh you are trying to show its less than nvm